# Work under GPL without license version number

Tags: licensing, gpl

I understand that I should consult a lawyer for this if this is is an important matter, but since it is not, I am just going to ask here.

What are the legal implications if one distribute their work with only the clause: This work is licensed under GNU GPL.

I have stumbled upon one such work. Since there is no "single" license called "GNU GPL" but only the versioned ones, does it equal to having no license information? Is there some 'common subset' of rights (of the different versions) that I am granted in this case?

As I understand, the differences in the versions are significant enough that Linus Torvalds has written an entire paragraph or two in Linux's License file.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Can anyone explain to me what is it that I'm not getting?

Comment: Questions about legal advice are off-topic on [softwareengineering.se]. You may want to consult a lawyer, or at least ask people who actually know what they are talking about, e.g. on [opensource.se] or [law.se], instead of a bunch of software engineers, who know stuff about software engineering, but probably not about international copyright law. Heck, most lawyers probably don't even know enough about international copyright law to feel comfortable answering your question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification; I wrongly assumed (based on other questions on other license topics) on where to ask or what might be an appropriate question. I think I have gotten the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jurisprudence recognizes intent - in fact, intent is pretty central to many decisions, to the point where presence of absence of intent can make the same act constitute two entirely different offenses. Considerable effort is often made to establish someone's intentions even when they are hard to get at (just consider what happens with unconscious terminally ill patients).

Therefore, if you published your code before GPL 3 existed, it's obvious that you didn't mean this version. If you keep publishing it until after the point where version 3 was introduced, this will almost certainly be taken to mean that you kept meaning version 2, etc.

Of course, it's always a good idea to be explicit about legal questions. Writing a sentence or a paragraph, like most projects do, isn't much effort, and in the unlikely case that you *do* get into a legal confrontation, it is always good to have as much of a basis for your claims as possible.

Comment: You can expect the rights the license gives you. *What* the license is, is decided by a judge based on the intent of the copyright holder. If you want a more explicit answer, you should consult a lawyer that specialized in international copyright law.